# Unable to find HTML button in aspx code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have following HTML button on my aspx form ,

```
<input type=button onclick="" value="change" id="btnChange" runat="server">
```

I'm trying following code to find my HTML button in code behind but it's not working,

```
Button b1=(Button)Page.findcontrol("btnChange");
b1.visible=false;
```

Comment: Is the button inside a template control (Repeater, Grid etc...) or outside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a server side control, you should be able to simply use `btnChange` directly to refer to it.

```
btnChange.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thanks @Oded. Actually I was using btnChange.Visible = false; but it was not working . It seems I have used "Style:Display-none" at my HTML button and was trying to make it visible=true through .NET.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a Button

```
 HtmlInputButton b1 = (HtmlInputButton) Page.findcontrol("btnChange");
 b1.visible=false;
```

Since you've added a `runat="server"` to it, you should try the intellisense of Visual Studio - it will bring it up

```
 btnChange.Visible = true; //should be recognized in code-behind
```